# How do I boot to BIOS directly from Ubuntu?

Tags: ubuntu, boot, partitioning, bios, uefi

Disclaimer: I have basically no experience with BIOS, UEFI, or anything of that kind.

Earlier today I installed Ubuntu 16.04 on my Acer Aspire V5-571 alongside Windows 10. (This laptop came with 8 pre-installed, so it had the quickboot thing enabled.) After the install, both worked fine, except I'd have to go into the UEFI settings and change the boot order in order to switch between Ubuntu and Windows. This is not a very bad thing, just an extremely minor annoyance that I decided to fix by switching to BIOS. (In retrospect, I don't see how that was supposed to help.) I went into my UEFI boot-order settings and hit the "Switch to BIOS" button. I also messed around with boot orders before that but can't remember exactly what I did. I seem to remember there being more than one entry for Windows, strangely...

Anyway, now it won't boot into Ubuntu or Windows, and I can't seem to access BIOS. When I hit the power button, it gives me this message:

```
(there's a copyright and patent message here)

Realtek PCIe GBE Family Controller Series v2.46 (03/23/12)
PXE-E61: Media test failure, check cable

PXE-M0F: Exiting PXE ROM.
```

Then it gives me a blank screen with `Operating System not found` in the upper-left corner.

I'm fairly certain it's *not* a problem with my hard drive cable, as I  can access all my files from both partitions no problem after booting from my Ubuntu 16.04 USB stick.

I have an SSD, and my computer boots so fast I only see the boot "ACER" logo screen for a split second. (I had to take a video with my phone and then freeze-frame it just to figure out what key I was supposed to press to open BIOS!) I've tried pressing/tapping <kbd>F1</kbd>, <kbd>F2</kbd>, <kbd>F8</kbd>, <kbd>F10</kbd>, <kbd>F11</kbd>, <kbd>F12</kbd>, and <kbd>Del</kbd>, but none of them seem to open BIOS. Right now the only way for me to get this computer to work at all is to boot from the USB stick I installed Ubuntu from!

I assume that I need to revert to UEFI boot, but I can't access BIOS in the conventional way. I have files I want in Windows, but not in Ubuntu.

I tried to reinstall/reset Ubuntu from the stick, but that gave me this:

> The partition table format in use on your disks normally requires you to create a separate partition for boot loader code. This partition should be marked for use as a "Reserved BIOS boot area" and should be at least 1 MB in size. Note that this is not the same as a partition mounted on /boot.
>
> If you do not go back to the partitioning menu and correct this error, boot loader installation may fail later, although it may still be possible to install the boot loader to a partition.

Hypothesis 1: Windows can boot directly to the UEFI settings from the "Restore Mode" thing WITHOUT having to hit F2 or whatever the key is. Is there an equivalent on USB-stick Ubuntu?

Comment: you are correct in that you must switch back to UEFI mode. Both operating systems you installed likely only work in UEFI mode. You should still be able to get in to bios by tapping the right key. Maybe you're not pressing it fast enough- try hitting the power button and then immediately repeatedly tapping the bios entry key until something happens

Comment: also, the restore mode from windows 10 is different from the bios. Bios is what you will have to access to change it back to UEFI

Comment: @Blaine I've started tapping the button before I even turn it on and it still wouldn't work. As far as bios vs restore, I'm aware that they're different but restore mode was (as far as I'm aware anyway) the only way to access my uefi settings. There's a button buried somewhere in it (can't remember where) that reboots directly into the actual uefi interface. I am kind of desperate for help, since I need this computer for Stanford ProCo tomorrow, you have any other suggestions?

Comment: well, this is unlikely, but have you tried a usb keyboard? I couldn't access bios on a computer before and it turned out that the built in keyboard was broken. I'll let you know if i think of anything else

Comment: The keyboard works fine with my Ubuntu stick...

Comment: oh, wait, here's something. If you're comfortable taking the computer apart to a minor extent, try resetting the bios to factory default settings (which should include uefi boot): unplug the  computer (and take out the battery if it's a laptop). Then find the cmos battery and unplug/remove it. Hold down the power button for 30 seconds while the battery is out. then put back the cmos battery as well as the laptop battery, and plug back in the computer. hopefully that fixes it... let me know if you have any questions on how to do this.

Comment: The two keys that seem to cover all Acer models are F2 and del. Don't try both in a single boot.  Just hammer on one from power application until you see the PXE indication ( which means it didn't work) Try a couple boots with each key, sometimes the timing is tight. As an alternative, many acers provide a bios reset via the F10 key. For that, press f10 with power off, and keep it pressed while applying power and letting it boot. If it works it will indicate so on screen and typically will allow to enter the bios via a menu option. A reset may be all you need in any event, if UEFI is default.

Comment: Clarification to previous comment. The system will beep twice if the F10 method to reset the bios works on some Acer systems.  You may not get any visual confirmation in that case. If you get 2 beeps and it doesn't reboot itself, wait a minute then manually power cycle. The documentation on their site is a bit self contradictory in places.

Comment: If you try all of this and get nowhere, the solution that is nearly guaranteed to work is a USB flash drive bios update. If you want to go that route, respond here and I, or someone else, will provide an answer with the howto's for that. You'll need another PC and a USB flash drive.

Comment: Will I need another computer or will my flash drive Linux work?

Comment: I would try resetting the bios via unplugging the cmos battery before i would try a bios flash as if done incorrectly, it can brick your computer

Comment: Disassembling computer now, I'll update you once I'm done

Comment: So when it's taken apart there is no power button... Will just having the cmos battery out for a while fix it?

Comment: @spelchekr haha, didn't think of that. you may be able to plug the power button strip in if you can, but otherwise yeah, leaving it out <i>should</i> work. Otherwise, you can try reasembling the computer and powering on without the battery installed. This will reset the settings, but will also reset the settings every time you unplug the laptop. if you go this route, you will want to take it apart and put it back in afterwards

Comment: I literally had to take out everything to get at the battery, how much do I have to put together? Just the disk, disk and cd drive, screen, anything?

Comment: Well, this is the first time that I've heard that flashing a bios was potentially more harmful than physically disassembling a laptop. I hope it works - it's another road to the same place. For any others reading; when you take apart laptops you will frequently find tiny little random plastic pieces that break extremely easy, so be very slow, patient and careful during the process; I usually end up with a little bit less holding the thing together afterwards. For modern home PCs with integrated usb bios rescue capability - e.g. this one, there is nearly no risk from a bios update.

Comment: @spelchekr i guess it shouldn't really matter at this point. just leave the cmos battery out for a minute or so, press the power button if you can (no big deal if you can't) and reasemble the whole thing. hopefully bios will be reset

Comment: It's almost all the way back together (just have a bunch of screws to put in) and windows booted! Thank you guys for all your help!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just writing an answer to summarize what helped the OP in the end (from the comments section).

Though you should be able to get into bios from tapping the F2 key repeatedly, this did not work for OP. The solution therefore is to reset the bios to default settings so that you can access it again. To do this:

1) Unplug AC power and take out the battery.

2) Figure out where the cmos battery is located on your computer. Take the computer apart until you can get to it

3) Take out/unplug the cmos battery and if possible, hold the power button down for 30 seconds. (If this is not possible, just leave the battery out for 2 minutes)

4)put the cmos battery back in, and fully reassemble the computer. BIOS settings should now be default, and you should be able to enter the BIOS again.

Answer (score -2):

The correct key should be F2, try pressing it right from power on with your laptop or external keyboard.  You may also get idea from this [official source](http://acer.custhelp.com/app/answers/detail/a_id/27103#_ga=1.222558553.357378733.1463192945)

Comment: Thank you for reporting the correct key, but this is not a very helpful answer as OP has already tried this and reported that it does not work.